# Spatialite in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, gdal, spatialite, ogr2ogr

Using the latest `setup-x86_64_2.919` to install Cygwin, I just noticed that Spatialite is not there. So, I installed it from the source code (`libspatialite-5.0.1.tar.gz`) and I re-installed `gdal-3.5.1` from the setup file. It seems that gdal has not been compiled with Spatialite. Interestingly, the same happens although I installed `gdal-3.5.1` from the source code. I just want to use the magic `-sql sqlite` call with the `ogr2ogr` command, so if anyone knows how to deal with Spatialite in Cygwin I would appreciate suggestions.

Any hints are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current Cygwin package of `gdal` is NOT compiled with `SpatiaLite` but it is compiled with indirect SQLite dependecy

```
 $ cygcheck gdalinfo
 ...
    D:\cygwin64\bin\cyggeotiff-5.dll
      D:\cygwin64\bin\cygproj-25.dll
        D:\cygwin64\bin\cygsqlite3-0.dll
 ...
```

If you are interested to add `SpatiaLite` to Cygwin the best way is to offer yourself as maintainer
See some general information on
https://cygwin.com/packaging-contributors-guide.html

If you are interested, you should follow the Cygwin package maintainer mailing list
https://cygwin.com/mailman/listinfo/cygwin-apps/

After that, adding `SpatiaLite` dependency to `Gdal` is a minor issue that will be handled by the `gdal` package maintainer

https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/gdal-src.html